# TypeError: setState is not a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const { useState } = React;

//To display current time
const DateTime = () => {
  setInterval(getTime, 1000);

  let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  const [currentTime, updateTime] = useState(time);
  console.log(time);

  function getTime() {
    const newTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    updateTime(newTime);
  }
  return (
    <div className="date">
      <p>Time: {currentTime}</p>
      <button onClick={getTime}>Get Time</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div className="container">
    <DateTime />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am a beginner in React. I am trying to display the current time in a functional component using useState hook but I am getting the following error with respect to my setState(it is updateTime in my case)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Navbar.css";

//To display current time
function DateTime() {
  setInterval(getTime, 1000);

  let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  const [currentTime, updateTime] = useState(time);
  console.log(time);

  function getTime() {
    const newTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    updateTime(newTime);
  }
  return (
    <div className="date">
      <p>Time: {currentTime}</p>
      <button onClick={getTime}>Get Time</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DateTime;
```

Error in Codesandbox is as follows. I don't understand the reason for this error. Could someone please help?

```
TypeError
updateTime is not a function
getTime
/src/components/DateTime.jsx:14:4
  11 | 
  12 | function getTime() {
  13 |   const newTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
> 14 |   updateTime(newTime);
     |  ^
  15 | }
  16 | return (
  17 |   <div className="date">
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: It's not the problem that you asked about, but that call to `setInterval` isn't correct. If you want to start a timer on mount, do it in a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependencies array (and return a function that clears the interval, which will be called on unmount). More: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect The way you have it now will start a **new** timer every time your component function is called, which is every time it needs to render. That will quickly get out of control.

Comment: Make sure you are using React 16.8 or above in your package.json

Comment: @fjplaurr - If they weren't, the error would be on `useState`, not `updateTime`.

Comment: Perhaps define your callbacks *before* they are used/referenced, try moving `const [currentTime, updateTime] = useState(time);` to the top of the function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your snippet is that you're trying to use React v15, which didn't have hooks. That's why it says `useState` is not defined.

The secondary problem is what I described in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700569/typeerror-setstate-is-not-a-function-in-react#comment119664715_67700569): You need to change how you set your interval timer up. If you want to start a timer on mount, do it in a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook with an empty dependencies array (and return a function that clears the interval, which will be called on unmount). The way you have it now will start a new timer every time your component function is called, which is every time it needs to render. That will quickly get out of control.

Here's a version with:

1. An up-to-date version of React
2. Setting up the timer using `useEffect`
3. Some further notes, see comments

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const DateTime = () => {
    let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    const [currentTime, updateTime] = useState(time);
    
    // Set up the interval timer using `useEffect`
    useEffect(() => {
        // Use a function local to this so it only gets created once
        // This isn't using `getTime` below because it would always
        // use the first one (and a linter would warn you that you
        // needed to add it as a dependency to `useEffect`, but we
        // know we don't want to).
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            const newTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
            updateTime(newTime);
        }, 1000);
        // Return a cleanup function...
        return () => {
            // ...that cancels the interval timer.
            clearInterval(timer);
        };
    }, []);

    // You don't need this if you don't need the button below
    function getTime() {
        const newTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        updateTime(newTime);
    }
  
    return (
        <div className="date">
            <p>Time: {currentTime}</p>
            {/* Do you really need this button since you have the timer? */}
            <button onClick={getTime}>Get Time</button>
        </div>
    );
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <DateTime />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Is it necessary to clear the interval? I'm afraid I do not understand the reason it should be cleared when the code works as expected even without it.

Comment: @ELIASVET - Glad that helped! Yes, it's necessary. If you don't, the interval will keep running as long as the page is there, even if your component has been removed from the DOM. Suppose you had a parent container that rendered your component or didn't based on a flag that changed periodically. Every time that flag changed so that your component was rendered, you'd start a new timer, but you wouldn't stop them when the component was removed. Over time you'd build up dozens, hundreds, even thousands of running timers, slowing everything down.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thank you @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score -1):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const DateTime = () => {
    const getTime = () => new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    const [currentTime, updateTime] = useState(getTime());
    
    // Run this code once on load
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval= setInterval(() => 
            updateTime(getTime())
        , 1000);
 
        return () => {
            // clean up interval on unload
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, []);
  
    return (
        <div className="date">
            <p>Time: {currentTime}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <DateTime />
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
 

   <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
      <title>React App</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

As pointed out in the comments by TJ.Crowder, I made some mistakes in my answer. It has been updated to apply useEffect.
Please refer to his answer above for a more detailed explaination.

It is advisable to run interval codes in places like redux middlewares, or useEffect where cleanup is possible.

Comment: Passing the function to `setInterval` doesn't call it and so won't cause an issue with that function trying to call `updateTime` before it's initialized, and the function decl is hoisted, so it doesn't matter where the `setInterval` call is in relation to the function decl. So moving where `setInterval` is doesn't change anything. The only reason the above works is the change in React version, and it still has the problem of setting up endlessly-more `setInterval` timers that I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700569/#comment119664715_67700569).

Comment: I see that is informative, i'll edit my answer accordingly thanks :)

Comment: Thank you too @Isaac Khoo.  T.J.Crowder, this is very helpful, thanks.